# IE8 page not loading correctly CDN jquery maybe?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

The issue i have is that my product pages dont seem to load correctly in IE8 yet is fine in all other main browsers.
Im using google's ajax libraries for the main scripts could this cause me the issue?

an example page would be: http://www.hollinwoodhydroponics.co.uk/lighting-accessories/lumii-600w-kit 
(loads fine in firefox, safari, chrome just not IE8)

any help will be great thank you.

Comment: What doesn't load correctly in IE? Have you checked your console to see if it logs an error?

Comment: yes, i had an  error fixed it and receive no errors in console now.
however the ajax and buttons dont work in IE8 - also my sidebar has disappeared off the page.

Comment: managed to dig deeper and an error code is now presented as: Unable to modify the parent container element before the child element is closed (KB927917) - again thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because you're calling your jQuery code on page load, but without waiting for the page to be finished loading.

In theory it shouldn't be working in any browsers. The only reason it's working at all in some browsers is because those browsers are rendering the page fast enough that they're finished before the JS code runs.

jquery provides a `.ready()` function specifically for this issue. All your setup code on the page which you want to run on page load should be wrapped in a `.ready()` function call, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //your code here.....
});
```

This will prevent it from being called too early, and make it work properly in all browsers.

Comment: But browsers execute JS at the point the `<script>` block is encountered while parsing the page, and _they don't continue parsing the rest of the page until the JS is finished_. There's no "race" condition where maybe the whole page will render in time and maybe it won't. `.ready()` lets you specify that a particular function won't be called until after the DOM is ready, which is probably necessary in this case but isn't always.

Comment: I would have spent a full jar of coffee on finding the cause let alone resolving it, so thank you very much on your help Spudley...
Resolving it Pt.1.. :)

Comment: after researching i did find that IE doesnt like it if it isnt wrapped as such, so i will try the recommended post before I can agree or disagree with nnnnnn but thanks for helping me guys.

Comment: @nnnnnn - given the error message he quoted in the comments on the question, the problem is definitely down to calling DOM manipulation function before the DOM is finished building.

Comment: OK, but I don't think that contradicts my previous comment. It's not a question of speed.

Comment: that wasn't the issue but for anyone else with this problem, it was a bug in my IE8 making the problem, i deleted and reinstalled and this fixed it. thanks to all who tried to help